# Ajax request to JSON file not working

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have an HTML table which I'm trying to populate with data that's stored in an external JSON file. I'm trying to make an AJAX request on it using pure JavaScript (no JS libraries), but nothing happens when I click on my "Test" button; the data won't populate. Here is my JSON file:

```
{   "row":[

 {
     "ID" : "2",
     "FirstName" : "John",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "03-12-1959",
     "Gender":"M"
    },

     {
     "ID" : "3",
     "FirstName" : "Helen",
     "LastName" : "Test",
     "DOB": "03-12-1959",
     "Gender":"M"
    }

]
}
```

Some of my HTML code:

```
<button onclick="loadJSON()">Test</button>
<table class="test-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>DOB</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="data">
    <tr>
      <td><label for="row1"></label>123</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>02-15-1982</td>
      <td>M</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

And my JavaScript code:

```
function loadJSON(){
     var data_file = "test.json";
            var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            try{
               // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
               http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }catch (e){
               // Internet Explorer Browsers
               try{
                  http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

               }catch (e) {

                  try{
                     http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }catch (e){
                     // Something went wrong
                     alert("Your browser broke!");
                     return false;
                  }

               }
            }

            http_request.onreadystatechange = function(){

               if (http_request.readyState == 4  ){

                  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
                  var tr, td;
                  var tbody = document.getElementById("data");

    // loop through data source
    for (var i=0; i<jsonObj.row.length; i++) {
        tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.setAttribute("align", "center");
        td.innerHTML = jsonObj.row[i].ID;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = jsonObj.row[i].FirstName;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = jsonObj.row[i].LastName;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = jsonObj.row[i].DOB;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = jsonObj.row[i].Gender;

    }

}

http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
http_request.send();
  }
```

Where did I go wrong here and what can I do to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the click method fire (have you placed a log in there to be sure)? If so - in the network tab do you see the request get made?

Comment: I placed an alert here: `function loadJSON() { alert("test");....` and the alert fires, but it doesn't seem like the request is being made. I get these errors: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file: (test.json).Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource` and the error points to this line: `http_request.send();` . That line also has an `Uncaught Syntax error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss one closing braquet `}` in your function just before `http_request.open()`...
Try with this one and will work.

### HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="loadJSON()">Test</button>
    <table class="test-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>DOB</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="data">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="row1"></label>123</td>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>02-15-1982</td>
                <td>M</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function loadJSON() {
        var data_file = "test.json";
        var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        try {
            // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
            http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            // Internet Explorer Browsers
            try {
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

            } catch (e) {

                try {
                    http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }

        http_request.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (http_request.readyState == 4) {

                var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
                var tr, td;
                var tbody = document.getElementById("data");

                // loop through data source
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.row.length; i++) {
                    tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
                    td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                    td.setAttribute("align", "center");
                    td.innerHTML = jsonObj.row[i].ID;
                    td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                    td.innerHTML = jsonObj.row[i].FirstName;
                    td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                    td.innerHTML = jsonObj.row[i].LastName;
                    td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                    td.innerHTML = jsonObj.row[i].DOB;
                    td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
                    td.innerHTML = jsonObj.row[i].Gender;

                }

            }
        }; // <----- This is the one you left off

        http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
        http_request.send();
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### JSON file

```
{
    "row": [

        {
            "ID": "2",
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Test",
            "DOB": "03-12-1959",
            "Gender": "M"
        },

        {
            "ID": "3",
            "FirstName": "Helen",
            "LastName": "Test",
            "DOB": "03-12-1959",
            "Gender": "M"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I made the changes but it still won't load the data.

Comment: I made  a simple html file with that content and it work's...  Did you recive any warnings in the console?

Comment: I edit my answer and post the exact code I test (and works)... any feedback?

Comment: This works, I can't believe I missed that bracket! Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, glad to help.